# import/export db configuration

Tags: java, mysql

We have a java portal connected to a mysql db containing about 70 tables.

When we prepare a new client on it, we test it on a DEV server and if all work good
we **DO THE SAME** configuration on PRODUCTION.

Well, we want to build some simple tool to **EXPORT** this configuration from DEV and **IMPORT** it to PRODUCTION. (to avoid doing it by hand every time)

We think about doing this with REST. ***GET*** from DEV and ***POST*** to PRODUCTION.
This configuration implies about 7-8 tables.

*What do you recommend? Do you think REST is the best decision?*

Answer (score 0):

I think REST is a a bit strange decision for this, as you would need to build and maintain the client and server software for handling the file uploads, and have it installed correctly on both machines.

I would use an automated secure copy (SCP) script to copy your build artefacts.

Comment: Hi Adriaan. Please note that i'm not talking about relase/deploy but about some configurations for my portal which are directly related to some database tables.

Comment: I don't think that really makes a difference, I'd still use SCP. If there is information we are missing, please elaborate.